# How to drop duplicates ignoring one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with multiple columns and the last column  is `timestamp` which I want Python to ignore. I've used `drop_columns(subset=...)` but does not work as it returns literally the same `DataFrame`.

This is what the `DataFrame` looks like:

|  | id | name | features | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34233 | Bob | athletics | 04-06-2022 |
| 2 | 23423 | John | mathematics | 03-06-2022 |
| 3 | 34233 | Bob | english_literature | 06-06-2022 |
| 4 | 23423 | John | mathematics | 10-06-2022 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

And this is are the data types when doing `df.dtypes`:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| id | int64 |
| name | object |
| features | object |
| timestamp | object |

Lastly, this is the piece of code I used:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=df.columns.tolist().remove("timestamp"), keep="first").reset_index(drop=True)
```

The idea is to keep track of changes based on a timestamp **IF** there are changes to the other columns. For instance, **I don't want to keep row 4** because nothing has changed with John, however, **I want to keep Bob** as it has changed from `athletics` to `english_literature`. Does that make sense?

**EDIT:**

This is the full code:

```
"""
db_data contains 10 records
new_data contains 12 records but I know only 5 are needed based on the logic I want to implement
"""
db_data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM subscribed", engine)
new_data = pd.read_csv("new_data.csv")

# Checking columns match
# This prints "matching"
if db_data.columns == new_data.columns: print("matching")

df = pd.concat([db_data, new_data], axis=1)

consider = [x for x in df.columns if x != "timestamp"]
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=consider).reset_index(drop=True)

# This outputs 22 but should have printed 15
print(len(df))
```

**TEST:**
I've done a test but has puzzled me even more. I've created a separate table in the db and loaded the csv file `new_data.csv` and then used `read_sql` to get it back into a `DataFrame`. Surprisingly, this works. However, I do not want to take this unnecessary extra step. I am puzzled on why this works. I've checked the data types they match.

```
db_data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM subscribed, engine")
new_data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM test, engine")

# Checking columns match
# This still prints "matching"
if db_data.columns == new_data.columns: print("matching")

df = pd.concat([db_data, new_data], axis=1)

consider = [x for x in df.columns if x != "timestamp"]
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=consider).reset_index(drop=True)

# This the right output... in other words, it worked.
print(len(df))
```

Comment: Have you tried `df = df[:-1]`? Or this is too specific for your problem?

Comment: It wouldn't work. I want to keep track of timestamps.

Comment: Do you want to keep the whole row except the column `timestamp`? or do you want to drop the whole row if it was a duplicate of a previous row?

Comment: Essentially, I want to delete rows that are duplicated, even if timestamp has changed.

Comment: So please take a look at the answer I have posted and let me know if it works.

Comment: The answer you posted wouldn't work. For instance, if I apply such code, I will keep rows 2 and 4 and I don't need to keep the two since John hasn't changed `features`. It is important that if there are no changes to `features` the other rows that match with a different timestamp are also removed.

Comment: No, if you do, as I said, row number 4 would get removed. If it does not, then please update your question with a code so that I can reproduce your results.

Answer (score 0):

The `remove` method of a list returns `None`. That's why the returned dataframe is similar. You can do as follows:

1. Create the list of columns for the subset: `col_subset = df.columns.tolist()`
2. Remove timestamp: `col_subset.remove('timestamp')`
3. Use the col_subset list in the `drop_duplicates()` function: df.drop_duplicates(subset=col_subset, keep="first").reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: Just tried but it doesn't work, it returns the same dataframe.

Comment: Does the created `col_subset` list include all desired columns, except for `timestamp`?

Comment: `col_subset` display the desired columns except for `timestamp`. Then I checked, and still keeping duplicated rows that have different timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
consider = [x for x in df.columns if x != "timestamp"]
df.drop_duplicates(subset=consider).reset_index(drop=True)
```

*(You don't need `tolist()` and `keep="first"` here)*

Comment: It feels like it should work but it is not working. I have checked there is nothing wrong by inserting the data into a database and getting rid of duplicates via SQL code... and it works. But I want to do it in Python!

Comment: That is very odd. It's working perfectly on my side. If you're working from a Jupyter\Ipython instance try to refresh the kernel. Otherwise share the full code so we can see if there's something else meddling with it.

Comment: I've just shared the full code.

Comment: Use this to see the difference if any: ```new_data_csv = pd.read_csv("new_data.csv")
new_data_sql = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM test, engine")

print(new_data_csv[new_data_csv!=new_data_sql].dropna(how='all'))```

Comment: @FrankJimenez sounds like there may be an issue on how you're loading your dataset. [Let's discuss this in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245333/chatting-with-965311532)

Comment: It shouldn't matter though, in the end, there's a dataframe that has duplicates but it isn't able to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this code would do:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='features', keep ='first').reset_index()
```